# Input change update price div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

So basically what I am trying to do is a simple cart update, with the total price and quantity change -> price update. I have ran into a problem which I cannot solve, jQuery is not my language but I understand the basic of it.

And  I would appreciate if you could tell me what I did wrong in that code and what I should think about in the future also if the total price will be able to update using two diffrent items and quantity.

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="280">
    <tr>
        <td width="140" valign="top" align="left"><div class="product_name">T-shirt, Black XS</div><div class="product_serial">Art.nr: <a href="javascript:void(0);">#TS4502-BL</a></td>
        <td width="30" valign="top" align="center"><input type="text" id="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" /></td>
        <td width="80" valign="top" align="center"><div class="product_total_cost" id="price" value="199">199 kr</div></td>
        <td width="9" valign="top" align="right"><div class="remove_product">X</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="280">
    <tr>
        <td width="110" valign="middle"><div class="procental_off">-10%</div><div class="cart_total_cost" id="total"> 358,2 kr</div></td>
        <td width="70" valign="middle" align="center"><div class="cart_clear">Rensa</div></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top" align="right"><div class="cart_continue">Fortsätt</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the following jQuery code I found on the internet and tried to make it work with my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#quantity').change(function(event) {
        $('#price').html($('#quantity').val()* $('#price').val());
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: And where did you put the script in relation to the HTML, as there's no DOM ready handler ?

Comment: I put it right under the HTML code, it works on the website but updates the wrong value. I tried with the DOM handler but it did not work intendedly. @adeneo

Comment: On line 5 @JohnHartsock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#price` is a div and does not have a value (even if you typed it, it's invalid)

You may want to consider something like this

```
$('#quantity').change(function (event) {
    $('#price').html($(this).val() * parseInt($('#price').text(), 10));
      // parseInt converts in this case strings to integers
});
```

EDIT: The problem now is that you have to reset the price... didn't see that at first

http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8hfxU/1/

---

**NEW:** You can for example store the price in a `data-*` attribute and retrieve it from there

http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8hfxU/2/

```
<div class="product_total_cost" id="price" data-val="199">199 kr</div>
```

And script

```
$('#quantity').change(function (event) {
    $('#price').html($(this).val() * parseInt($('#price').attr('data-val'), 10));
});
```

Comment: Yes but if you add 5 more in the quantity the price is correctly but if you change it back to 1 the price shows for the quantity of 5. @Spokey

Comment: So later when I convert the testing html fake products and prices with the real ones from the database i just add <?php $get['price']; ?> in the data-val? @Spokey

Comment: The second item value does not change at all, is there a conflict in between? Also how would I be calculating the total price of one item and total price of another and show the $total_price of the whole cart? @Spokey

Comment: @PrinceSamuel are you using the same ID (like `#price`) more times?

Comment: Yes, creating a new ID for each item added would make the automatic work for the website tricky. @Spokey

Comment: @PrinceSamuel well that's whay it's not working :) JS will only take the first ID since they *must* be unique. Changing to class is the best option.... this may complicate things a little http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8hfxU/4/

Comment: So let's say that we have like 10 items in the cart, for each item it has to be a unique ID, it would look messy to have #price_1, #price_2 how do we make this clean? @Spokey

Comment: @PrinceSamuel use classes instead of ID if you have more of the same

Comment: What do you mean? Like switch out the ID to classes? @Spokey

Comment: @PrinceSamuel yes, see my fiddle above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mh8hg/ I made a fiddle with the full code of the cart and the updated jQuery solution you made, it is not working. It has to with the 'Parent' I think. @Spokey

Comment: @PrinceSamuel You have to include jQuery from the left panel. Then the problem is that you have 2 class attributes (you changed id to class) and the 2nd one will be ignore, so type all your classes only in one class attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Mh8hg/1/

Comment: Yeah that solved it, did not realise that. Thanks for the help once again, also a last question. How do I multiply the value for each price to show in the total_price? @Spokey

Comment: I was working with a code similiar to the one you just posted, but your solution was better. @Spokey

Answer (score 1):

You cannot target a `<div>` `value` property as `val()` as it is not an input. Target it as follows if you would like to keep the value property:

```
$("#price").attr("value")
```

This comes with the benefit of keeping the curreny SEK `kr` without it being a problem.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" /><div id="price" value="199">199 kr</div>
```

Javascript(jQuery):

```
$(function() {

    $("#quantity").on("change keyup paste", function () {

        $("#price").html((parseInt($("#quantity").val())*parseInt($("#price").attr("value"))) + " kr");

    });

});
```

Working jsfiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnUw5/1/).

Note the `change keyup paste`. If you only put change, the event fires only when focus leaves the input  box.

Comment: What happens when you multiply though? How will you display that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#quantity').change(function(event) {
        $('#price').html(parseFloat($('#quantity').val())* parseFloat($('#price').val()));
    }); 
</script>
```

The reason why I used `parseFloat` is to parse the value (which is by default considered as string in Javascript/Jquery). So it is needed to be parsed to float so mathematical operations can be performed upon the parsed values. You may alternatively use `parseInt` to conver the values to `integer`

Comment: The #price div does not *allow* a value, it isn't an input.

Comment: Exactly what Jay said, but I did try with the val and put a value on the div but I do not think it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what you're logic is and consider your markup. First, you cannot use duplicate id's in a page, so if you have more than one product in the page setup like this, you'll run into problems. Second, the div #price cannot have a value because it isn't a proper attribute for a div. Given that, you have to turn the text into an integer so that it can be multiplied -

```
 $('#quantity').change(function(event) {
     console.log('foo');
        $('#price').html($('#quantity').val()* parseInt($('#price').text()));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J54n9/

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#quantity').change(function(event) {
        $('#price').html($('#quantity').val()* parseInt($('#price').attr('value')));
    }); 
</script>
```